# Passing list element to str_replace in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to pass a list element to R's `str_replace` function. Say I have a string:

`a <- 'A dog is small'` and a list `l <- c('big','medium')`. I want to replace small with first list element, but this will not work because the function expects something in between quatation marks.

```
b<-str_replace(a,'small',l[1])
```

How do I tell R I want a string corresponding to `l[1]`.

Comment: What was the error message you got? I tried running your code, and it successfully replaced "small" with "big".

Comment: Your example gives `l` as a character vector, rather than a list. If you are actually using a list `l <- list('big','medium')` you will need to put the index in double square brackets: `b<-str_replace(a,'small',l[[1]])`